# Media Files not shown in DEBUG=False Django 2.2.6

Tags: django, cpanel

Every thing works perfect in debugging mode but can't show the media files on production environment while debugging id false

That's my settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
)

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticroot')

# Media folder for database media
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and the project urls

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
                        settings.STATIC_URL,
                        serve,
                        document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
                        )
    urlpatterns += static(
                        settings.MEDIA_URL,
                        serve,
                        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
                        )
```

Although the url link path shows perfectly using template tags

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<a href="{{ magazine.document.url }}" target="_blank">
      <i class='far fa-file-pdf'></i>
 </a>
```

Hope you can help to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you setup a web server? When DEBUG=False no url resolution will take place for static files.

Generally in production your nginx (or Apache) server will be the server serving your static assets.

Comment: @MattSeymour No I didn't setup a web server .. I just collectstatic on my PC and all static files works fine .. but media files not shown when debugging mode is False.. and this is the same issue on my hosting server using cpanel platform

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs on cpanel? It might be a permissions issue.

Comment: @MattSeymour I think it's something related to cpanel because.. I tried now debugging True it gives me Raised by:django.views.static.serve 

.. however, for media images works fine .. this error for PDF files only

Comment: When debugging is true you are serving your media files through the `if settings.DEBUG:` in the urls.py. Serving static files when DEBUG=True is really not recommended and should not be seen as a solution. The issue is somewhere in your cpanel config (something i know little about). It might be worth rephrasing your question on a cpanel form as its not a django specific issue, rather a configuration issue.

Comment: @MattSeymour but why I'm facing this issue when debugging is False on my pc

Comment: Because when debug is false there is no URL route available to serve the media files. In your current setup the urls for serving a media file is only present when debug is true

Comment: @MattSeymour I checked links given for images files (which is working fine in debugging False) and the PDF files .. they are the same but PDF files not working... Something wrong on serving document files I think

Comment: @MattSeymour /media/magazine/08770c5a-42b1-4b45-99f9-b9e311840cf8.pdf .. this link not working .. /media/events/d0ca0f2c-e228-4923-b5f3-6d74c7595661.jpg .. this link working fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django is not loading media files on shared hosting cPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299083/django-is-not-loading-media-files-on-shared-hosting-cpanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault PDF files must be downloaded or viewed by third party viewer.. and for debugging mode I must have Apache server to work when debugging is False.