# Django is not loading media files on shared hosting cPanel

Tags: html, css, django

I am having issues loading media files uploaded by the user and displaying them via a template.html file when DEBUG = FALSE. The static files are displayed but I keep getting `webaddress/media/images/image1.png 404 Not Found` whenever I load the page. I followed some guides and added `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to my `urls.py` but I am still getting the 404 error. I've chatted with the cPanel hosting provider and they said I do not have access to modify the cPanel Apache httpd.conf file so I am looking to have Django manage the serving of the media files since it handles the uploading of images to the `media/images` directory.

Location where images directory is: `/home/<cPanelUserName>/repositories/djangoApp/media/images`

```
settings.py

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

```
template/index.html

<body style="background: url('{{ background_pic.url }}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed;">
    <div id="profile">
        <img id="userPhoto" src="{{ profile_pic.url }}" alt="{{ profile_pic_title }}">
    </div>
</body>
```

```
models.py

class profilePic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

class backgroundPic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

```
views.py

def index(request):
    imageModel = profilePic.objects.get(pk=1)
    backgroundModel = backgroundPic.objects.get(pk=1)

    return render(
        request,
        "template/index.html",
        {
            "profile_pic_title":imageModel.title,
            "profile_pic":imageModel.image,
            "background_pic_title":backgroundModel.title,
            "background_pic":backgroundModel.image,
        }
    )
```

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('SocialLinks.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing your media root path to the `public_html` folder should help you (on shared hosting cPanel)

before (you have media files inside your project directory)

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/{username}/{project}/media' ✖️
```

after (now they are stored inside public_html folder)

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/{username}/public_html/media' ✔️
```